# Not getting an output when I call __str__ on a class instance?

Tags: python

I am just a beginner so be easy on me. i was just playing with the `__str__` method and found that when I try to print the instance it just doesn't work

```
import random

brand = ("Samsung","Nokia","Sony","ATAT","Reliance")
no_of_sim = ("Dual-sim","Single-sim")
color = ("Blue","Violet","Orange","Green")
no_of_camera =("Front","Front-Back","Back")
no_of_cores = ("Dual Core","Quad Core","Octa Core")
additional = ("Bluetooth","NFS","Gps")

class mobile:
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        name = self
        self.brand = random.choice(brand)
        self.sim = random.choice(no_of_sim)
        self.color = random.choice(color)
        self.camera = random.choice(no_of_camera)
        self.cores = random.choice(no_of_cores)
        self.additional = random.choice(additional)
        for key,value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self,key,value)
    def __str__(self):
        return "{} Is a {} color {} phone with {} facing cameras and it a {} with {}".format(self.__class__.__name__,self.color,self.brand,self.camera,self.cores,self,additional)
```

```
from mobile_phone import mobile
swiss = mobile()
print(swiss)
# It doesnt show up
```

Comment: Can you elaborate further on "It just doesn't work"?  From your question, it's unclear to me what _is_ being printed when you try to run this code.  It also appears that you may have some indentation errors -- at least in the code you've shown here (check to make sure you aren't mixing tabs and spaces in your original source).

Comment: @mgilson so it is, my bad. OP, when I fixed the indentation, I get a recursion error. Please give a [mcve].

Comment: ```self,additional``` comma instead of a dot??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a comma where you need a dot:

```
import random

brand = ("Samsung","Nokia","Sony","ATAT","Reliance")
no_of_sim = ("Dual-sim","Single-sim")
color = ("Blue","Violet","Orange","Green")
no_of_camera =("Front","Front-Back","Back")
no_of_cores = ("Dual Core","Quad Core","Octa Core")
additional = ("Bluetooth","NFS","Gps")

class mobile:
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        name = self
        self.brand = random.choice(brand)
        self.sim = random.choice(no_of_sim)
        self.color = random.choice(color)
        self.camera = random.choice(no_of_camera)
        self.cores = random.choice(no_of_cores)
        self.additional = random.choice(additional)
        for key,value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self,key,value)
    def __str__(self):
        return("{} Is a {} color {} phone with "
               "{} facing cameras and it a {} with {}".format(
                    self.__class__.__name__,
                    self.color,
                    self.brand,
                    self.camera,
                    self.cores,
                    self.additional))  # changed from self,additional

#from mobile_phone import mobile
swiss = mobile()
print(swiss)
```

Output:

```
mobile Is a Green color Reliance phone with Front-Back facing cameras and it a Dual Core with Bluetooth
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in the end of **str** method:

```
self,additional
```

It makes **str** method recursive. Changing "," to "." removes the problem.